# Code to find physical location from IP Address

Tags: apex, geolocation

I need to find out the physical location of a client based on his IP Address. I have been able to retrieve the IP Address. Is there a way to find the geographic location from that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this specifically using Salesforce constructs.

Take a look at some of the available options online around converting IP addresses to location data to see if any have APIs you can integrate into a trigger with a callout. I haven't used any of these, but Google search is your friend :)

- http://www.ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php
- http://www.telize.com/
- http://freegeoip.net/

Comment: A callout was the first thing that I had tried and was able to get what I needed. I was looking for Salesforce constructs to do it instead but I guess as you and Christian Deckert mentioned, that isn't possible. Thank You for the response though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to get the location from IP addresses. Therefore you have to call an external service which returns the geolocation based on a given IP address.

e.g. freegeoip.net